# How did the displaced persons know how to carry on once Sam Beckett jumped out of their bodies?

Tags: time-travel, quantum-leap

In Quantum Leap, Sam Beckett switched into other peoples bodies and changed, or restored, or ensured history that was guided to the history as it was known in Sam's own timeline. These people seemed to be kept isolated in a lab in Sam's (their future) timeline. Once Sam did his thing as dictated by that weeks mission, he leapt out and the displaced person returned to their place in time. Since they were unaware of the decisions and actions Sam performed in their name, how did they continue the altered timeline without unraveling Sam's activities?

Comment: It was my understanding from just watching QL that the **Swiss-cheese** of Sam's brain was due to his *jumping* into other people and "sharing" or "merging" with their mind as they basically do a body swap.  In fact there was more than one instance where Sam had some memories from the "host body" bleed into his.  It's not unreasonable to expect that he left many of the memories created while he was living his hosts life behind.  In fact in season 5 the three part episode story arc **Trilogy** has Sam visit the life of Abigail Fuller three times, so there you can see how life goes on post-leap.

Comment: Possible dup of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14169/did-sams-memories-transfer-to-the-displacee-when-he-leaped

Comment: @22nd Century Fza - that's not really right, Sam didn't actually leap into anyone's body or merge with their brain, he just physically switched places with people (the leapees appeared in the [Waiting Room](http://quantumleap.wikia.com/wiki/Waiting_Room) in Sam's own time), and somehow there was an illusion created that made Sam *look* like the person he had switched with (although Al still saw him as Sam, and the illusion could sometimes be broken for others, like what happened when Sam and [Alia](http://quantumleap.wikia.com/wiki/Alia), an "evil leaper", touched each other).

Comment: Although if you can think of specific examples where Sam seemed to have some of the memories of the person whose life he leaped into (I don't remember any stories where that happened but I haven't watched it in a while), I guess that would be evidence that there is some level of merging at the mental level (whether of the brain or the 'soul'), despite the fact that the leapee appears physically intact in the Waiting Room.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Now that you mention it I do recalled one episode where the person Sam leapt into had no legs but Sam could stand up... As for an example of Sam accessing the person's memory it was simply how I understood & remembered it from when I watched it years ago. While I did catch all of it I haven't seen it since I was a kid, so I have no specific examples to give.  My memory may be at fault here but as it seems a satisfying way to see it, now that I reflect on it.  So if it's all the same I'll just continue on remembering it this way, examples or no ;]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam would switch with the "leapee" and attempt to fix whatever they'd done to muck up their timeline. Generally this would be to affect a *single* bad decision rather than to make any large-scale lifestyle choices on their behalf. This means that once they'd returned, they would no longer be in a position to make that 'bad' choice and simply carry on with their lives as before.

Per the [Quantum Leap FAQ](http://www.finifter.com/quantum-leap/information/faql.html#mark5)

> **Q. What does the leapee remember about his experience after he returns?**
>
> This is also not known. The only time we've seen this occur was in the
> episode "Double Identity," where Sam leaped to replace another body
> and the original host returned. **He APPEARED to have no memory of
> anything after he was leaped into. It has been stated that the leapee,
> while in Sam's body back in the Waiting Room, has a 'swiss-cheesed'
> memory, much like Sam received upon his initial leap. Because of the
> ultramodern hospital-like atmosphere of the waiting room, many of the
> leapees believe they have been abducted by aliens.** Deborah Pratt says
> that as the leapees return, they pick up some of Sam's memories of
> what happened, but they believe the events happened to them.